# Isekai manga with over-powered main character that lives with over-powered old villagers

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for an Isekai manga where the main character grew up in a village full of over-powered villagers and was taught that he is weak and ordinary to humble him. When he left the village he thought that he was the weakest person but everyone around him saw him as super over-powered.

Comment: Hi. Is the [isekai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isekai) tag actually warranted? You don't describe the main character as being transported to another universe, or dying and being reincarnated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like ***[Suppose a Kid from the Last Dungeon Boonies Moved to a Starter Town](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=144928)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Follow the story of Loyd, an oblivious boy from a village in the countryside, who wishes to become a soldier in the capital. After convincing the mayor of his village, a loli witch, who is over a 100 years old, he sets off to the capital to fulfill his dream!

The protagonist, [Lloyd Belladonna](https://supposeakid.fandom.com/wiki/Lloyd_Belladonna), thinks little of himself, since he was the weakest person in the village he grew up in, and the other villagers constantly reminded him of it.

However, everyone in that village is abnormally strong, as they were all descended from heroes who'd saved the world in the past. Also, their village is located in an 'uninhabitable zone' bordering the demon world, so they're constantly fighting off monsters.

So, by the standards of normal people in other villages and towns, even the weakest person from that village, Lloyd, is incredibly strong, although he's completely oblivious of this fact.

[image]

[image]